# Error when checking model target: expected dense_2 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 4, 4)

Tags: keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

The shape of my labels right before I fit them is (32, 4, 4), my data to train right before being fit is (32, 28, 28, 3). When everything to feed it to the model, my data shape is (40, 28, 28, 3) and my labels are (40, 4).

Here is what my model looks like:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(28,28,3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(len(users), activation='softmax')) 
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, 
          batch_size=32, nb_epoch=1000, verbose=1)

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose=0)
```

What is going on to give my labels a third dimension?

Edit: I know my labels need to be (32, 4), and I pass them as (40, 4). I don't know where the (32, 4, 4) is coming from. It SHOULD be (32, 4), but it's getting a third dimension somewhere.

Comment: The labels require one less dimension, probably ( 32, 4 )

Comment: Yes, where is it getting the third dimension?

Comment: For that, you need to post the code which you used to process the data.

Comment: I found out I was doing y_train =to_categorical(y_train,len(users)) and it was adding another dimension.